# Print specific block from a region in drupal 7

Tags: views, migrations

The region name is "sidebar_first". and it has two blocks. How can I print this block separately. Please help. I can not find the way to print a specific block from a region in drupal 7.

Comment: Where do you want to print it? in a node / page / another block?

Comment: Any reason not to simply create 2 regions? Or move blocks around with CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
$module = 'my_module'; // This is the module that provides the hook_block_view
$delta = 'my_block'; // you can get $delta from moduel hook_block_info
$block = module_invoke($module, 'block_view', $delta);
print render($block['content']);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Do you give a example link?

Comment: @anikbiswas what example would you need? It's already copy-paste-adjust code that requires next to no real work on your part, and what you need to do is described in comments.